# Similarity and Prevalence in Binary Vectors

Tags: r, binary-data, matrix, similarities, jaccard-similarity

Let's say I have N vectors, all of length L. Each vector is binary, such that they comprise of 0s and 1s whereby a 0 represents an 'absence' and 1 represents a 'presence' of an element denoted by its column.

For example, think of two vectors that represent two shopping baskets. Which groceries are in each? Let's say we have five products (ie L = 5) we want to capture: **milk, eggs, cheese, bread, apples.** These are our 'columns' in fixed order.

Alice has bought eggs and bread. Bob has bought milk, eggs, cheese and apples.

Vector for Alice <- [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

Vector for Bob <- [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]

I would like a measure that captures the similarity across all N vectors. The way I have found to compute this is by first calculating the pairwise distance between each combination of two vectors, producing an N by N matrix where N(x,y) represents the distance/dissimilarity between vectors x and y. Originally, the distance measure I was using was the Euclidean distance (in R: `stats::dist(method="euclidean")`). However, given that I am using binary vectors of 0s and 1s, it seems that using Jaccard distances is more suitable (in R: `stats::dist(method="binary")`). With this matrix of distances, I would then take the mean distance as a measure of how similar the vectors are to each other overall.

***This brings up a question: is similarity necessarily conflated with prevalence? Here I am defining prevalence as the proportion of 1s across the N vectors overall.***

If we had vectors of length 30 and such vectors had 29 ones, there would be 30 possible combinations of vectors, where a zero occupies each possible position and the rest are ones. However, if you had an equal number of 0s and 1s, there are `30 choose 15` combinations of vectors. Hence, when prevalence is high or low, vectors are more likely to be similar, right?

When I use Jaccard distances, I observe a negative correlation between similarity and prevalence. But shouldn't this be more like a U shaped relationship? High and low prevalence should be treated equivalently. The aforementioned case of 29 ones should be the same as the one for 29 zeroes. So why is the relationship linear? I tried using other distance measures, like Jaccard index and Dice coefficient but in all cases, I have found similarity and prevalence to be closely related in a linear fashion.

I have been trying to figure out if it is possible to disentangle similarity and prevalence and if not, what the relationship between the two should look like. Does my intuition of a U-shaped relationship make sense between prevalence and similarity? It might be that I should not be surprised at the linear relationship or that I am using the wrong distance/similarity measure so I would appreciate any tips you might have. Thanks!